# Long delay after stop/start Google Speech Recognition service

Tags: google-cloud-speech

When initializing the Google speech recognition service, we see a response in around 300 milliseconds. However, if we stop the reco service and start it again, each subsequent "start" has a much longer delay before the service is ready to start receiving our audio stream. We've seen this time range anywhere between 5 seconds and 11 seconds.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be occurring?

-- ADDITIONAL INFORMATION --

2019-05-30:
Our development team is following closely the example that we found [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cpp-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/api/streaming_transcribe_singlethread.cc). The only difference is that we're not sending a file, instead we're redirecting an audio stream to this service.

When debugging our code, we see that the delay appears to be within these three lines..

```
auto creds = grpc::GoogleDefaultCredentials(); 
auto channel = grpc::CreateChannel( "speech.googleapis.com", creds ); 
std::unique_ptr<Speech::Stub> speech( Speech::NewStub( channel ) );
```

(These three lines are the first three lines in our stream create thread.)

Comment: What APIs or other procedures are you using to stop and restart the service?  What is the thinking behind why you are stopping and restarting it?

Comment: We stop/start the service on the same audio stream because the Google API only allows a maximum of 65 seconds. Since our audio stream lasts upwards of 2-3 minutes, we need to stop/start the service multiple times on the audio stream.

Comment: It feels like you could use https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize to handle audio input > 1 minute.  Would this be satisfactory?

Comment: It says to transcribe an audio file in excess if 1 minute. Can I use that process to transcribe a live audio stream?

Comment: Aparently not ... if we look here ...https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas  we see that the only way to transcribe audio > 1 minute is to capture all the audio and then provide it as a unit for asynchronous processing.

Comment: This won't be an option as we're using the service to transcribe words spoken on a phone call in real time. I'm adding a little more content to this ticket, hoping it will be helpful.